# How to use Xcode with a cloned git repository

Tags: xcode, github

I am new to gitHub and have been invited to work on a private project. I am familiar with XCode and would like to use it to work on the project for it's autocompletion capabilities that I am used to. My problem is I don't know how to set this up so that I can pull the git repository, edit and test in XCode and then push. I have gone through a few tutorials on setting up git in XCode and I am successful in being able to connect to a repository I have pulled, but don't know how to use this as an XCode project once I have done so.

Here are a few specifics:

I made an SSH key for my computer and have cloned the repository through the terminal. Obviously I can update the files here and then use git commit and git push, however I want to use XCode for editing for code completion.

This project has a make file, though I don't know how to use these other than just typing "make all" in the terminal. I am assuming that I can set this up with Xcode so that when I build it uses the make file, but reading the documentation on this made me realize I don't understand enough to set this up.

I have tried making an Xcode project and then importing my files, but the problem is that Xcode insists on making a directory inside the project folder with the same name as the project where it stores all of the files. Therefore all of the addresses for my header files become wrong.

I assume that cloning a git project and then editing in Xcode is pretty standard. Does anyone have a place I can go for help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download SourceTree from the app store. It's free and kicks ass. You can just clone it in the terminal window using 'git clone WhateverOneYouWant -b WhicheverBranch'. Then just drag the project from the finder into the main sourceTree window.

Or alternatively, you can just grab it directly from gitHub on the main opening page of xcode. If there are no projects currently open, in the left part of the opening window, you'll see a line that says 'connect to a repository'.

Let me know if you have questions!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an exact answer to your question, but it does work.

If you install git separately and clone from the command line, you can:

Use Spotlight to *Locate the Project folder you cloned*

Double click the corresponding .xcodeproj file and start editing.